# Javascript: can't find element

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

I've run into a strange problem: I'm trying to get a `<form>` element from javascript but I'm unable to.

my html code is created dynamically by php:

```
<form id="form_color_{$color->id}" action="?com=saveColor" method="POST">   
    <!--some input elements-->
    <a href="javascript:saveColor({$color->id})"> 
        <img src="{$webSiteUrl}assets/img/admin/floppy_disk_24.png" /> 
        <span> Save</span> 
    </a>
</form>
```

so the page will contain various `form_color_` forms like `form_color_1 form_color_2` etc...

when the image is clicked this javascript function is called:

```
function saveColor(id){
    $("#form_color_"+id).submit();
}
```

the funtion correctly receive the id param but it doesn't submit the form.

if I try to get the form element I get null

```
function saveColor(id){
    form = 'form_color_'+id;
    var doc = document.getElementById(form);
    alert(doc);
    $("#form_color_1").submit();
}
```

the function works perfectly with other forms.

here's an example of the code produced by php:

```
<form id="form_color_1" action="?com=saveColor" method="POST">
    <!--some input elements-->
    <a  href="javascript:saveColor(1)"> 
        <img imgc="http://10.10.10.46/c5liveOnLine/assets/img/admin/floppy_disk_24.png" /> 
        <span> Save</span> 
    </a>
</form>
```

what am I missing?

Comment: What does `console.log(id);` output?

Comment: it outpus the correct id

Comment: The code you've shown definitely **will** submit the form if it exists. We can't help you based on what's in the question, since it will work.

Comment: I really don't know what to say... the form exists. Can I post anything useful? I would avoid to post the whole source code since is very long.

Can the problem be related to the fact that multiple forms of the same structure exists?

Comment: @JacopoGrassi: You don't want to post a wall of code, but it should be possible to create an [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work, unless of course there's another form on the page with the same `id` (which would be bad).

But note that you don't need `id`s for this at all, and so if `id`s are the problem the solution is not to use them. Just give your triggering element a class:

```
<form action="?com=saveColor" method="POST">   
    <!--some input elements-->
    <a class="submit-form"> 
        <img src="{$webSiteUrl}assets/img/admin/floppy_disk_24.png" /> 
        <span> Save</span> 
    </a>
</form>
```

...and then use a handler to submit the form containing the element:

```
$(document).on("click", ".submit-form", function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

I used a delegated handler because I didn't see any reason not to, and it means you can add and remove forms dynamically if you need to.

---

But note that you don't need JavaScript for this at all, unless you're doing more than just submitting the form. `button` elements can be styled to look any way you want them to look, and their default action is to submit the form they're in. So:

```
<form action="?com=saveColor" method="POST">   
    <!--some input elements-->
    <button> 
        <img src="{$webSiteUrl}assets/img/admin/floppy_disk_24.png" /> 
        <span> Save</span> 
    </button>
</form>
```

Just use CSS to make the button look the way you want it to look.

Here's an example styling `button` to look like a link:

```css
button {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: blue;
}
button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<form action="?com=saveColor" method="POST">
  <!--some input elements-->
  <button>
    <img src="{$webSiteUrl}assets/img/admin/floppy_disk_24.png" />
    <span> Save</span> 
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, the first solution worked. still don't understand why though